# Force allocating real memory

Tags: macos, memory

Is it possible to allocate big chunk (512Mb-1Gb with 4Gb installed) of real memory without dropping it to swap?

My final intention is to free system memory: os x has a problem when free memory is near 0 — it doesn't try hard to put unused memory to swap and everything becomes very slow trying to get memory. So, I decided that if some process grabs some memory (I grab 1/8 to 1/4 of total system memory) by force, and than frees it, than system will become responsible again.
I wrote little ruby script which created and filled memory disk (`hdiutil` is the only way I found to grab real memory using external utils) and now I decided to rewrite it using just C.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14157002/can-calloc-or-malloc-be-used-to-allocate-only-physical-memory-in-osx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [mlock](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/mlock.2.html) function will lock pages into physical memory.  I'm not sure what the limits are.

You should be extremely sure you really want to do this.  It's not a nice thing to do to the rest of the system.

Comment: Already found reading man pages :) But for someone it will be easier to find answer. I'll explain why I did this in question.

Comment: Ah.  See also /usr/bin/purge.  It doesn't do the same thing, but it will typically free up a lot of memory.

Comment: Ouch! purge is hard, it works good (it freed about 1Gb of unused memory), but it unpleasantly totally freezes system for 20-30 seconds. Though thank you for sharing knowledge!